# Create variable for Column name

Tags: python, pandas

Not sure if anyone can help however I am trying to create a Variable which I can use for calling a column name instead of identifying the column name using a string. This is so that I can always go back to change the value for my Target Variable and then run the whole code instead of having to keep going to different cells to change the string.
So far I have seen that I could use the statement:
`TargetCountry = CountryDF['UK']` (Uk would be the Column Name)

However, when I run:

```
TargetNot0= CountryDF.loc[CountryDF[TargetCountry] != 0]
TargetNot0
TargetNot0.sort_values(by=TargetCountry, ascending=False)
```

- I get a Key error saying '[0.  0.  0.  ... 0.  0.  2.4] not in index'

Would anyone know a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

`TargetCountry = CountryDF['UK']`
this should probably be
`TargetCountry = 'UK'`

the line you are using translates to:
`TargetNot0= CountryDF.loc[CountryDF[CountryDF['UK']] != 0]`
and not:
`TargetNot0= CountryDF.loc[CountryDF['UK'] != 0]`

Comment: If I don't put square brackets around 'UK' - Would this still identify UK as a column name? I wanted to call the column name from the CountryDF dataframe

Comment: aslong as you put TargetCountry in brackets "UK" will be in brackests.

Answer (score 0):

`TargetNot0= CountryDF.loc[CountryDF[TargetCountry] != 0]` is equivalent to `TargetNot0= CountryDF.loc[CountryDF[CountryDF['UK']] != 0]`, but with this, CountryDF can't have access to the column 'UK' and will instead try to have access to [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 2.4] (i.e, CountryDF['UK'] values). 
To resolve this problem, you should simply write: `TargetCountry = 'UK'`.